# Linker error in compilation of a simple c program : "undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status"

Tags: linker-errors, mingw32

I have made a simple C program as follows :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()  {
   
// printf() displays the string inside quotation
   
printf("Hello, World!");
  
return 0;    
}
```

I have installed `MINGW32` with my windows 10 OS. after giving the following command-:

```
E:\gcc -o hello hello.c
```

I get the following error

```
C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../libmingw32.a(setargv.o):(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

please help me with this I am new to this stuff

Solution of the above mentioned program .. and reason why this error occured . as well as about MingW32